# MongoDb - Pop array element based on if condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update my mongo database which has following structure.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a64d076bfd103df081967ae"),
"values" : [ 
    {
        "date" : "2018-01-22",
        "Price" : "1289.4075"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "2018-01-22",
        "Price" : "1289.4075"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "2015-05-18",
        "Price" : 1289.41
    }
],
"Code" : 123456,
"schemeStatus" : "Inactive"
}
```

I want to compare first 2 array element's date value i.e values[0].date and values[1].date. If both matches then I want to delete values[0] so that there will be only 1 entry with that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework's pipeline with [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) as a last stage to update your collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            sameDate: {
                $let: {
                   vars: {
                      fst: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 0 ] },
                      snd: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 1 ] }
                   },
                   in: { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$$fst.date", "$$snd.date" ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } }
                }
             }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            values : { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$sameDate", 0 ] }, then: "$values", else: { $slice: [ "$values", 1, { $size: "$values" } ] } } },
            Code: 1,
            schemeStatus: 1
        }
    },
    { $out: "collection" }
])
```

Some more important operators used here:

- [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) to handle if-else logic
- [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to define some helper variables
- [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to get first and second element
- [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/index.html) to pop first element

Comment: Thanks @mickl for the reply. I am not sure but can we update the database with the above code. Here we are getting the result into new collection. I tried to modify above code and update collection but not able to achieve the result.

Comment: @Jitesh $out can redirect the output to a new collection (which copies the data) or to the same collection which results in updating the data